# Git WARNING: Your password has expired. on OpenShift

Tags: git, ssh, openshift

When using Openshift and git there have never been any problems pushing to the repository. But today it stopped working. I can't git push, not from my local machine and not from cloudenvy.

The console states:

```
WARNING: Your password has expired.
Password change required but no TTY available.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I try cloning again using the SSH-string you get logged on to the OpenShift online the same message appears.

What do you do to change the password so I can carry on with the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue on OpenShift Online and should be resolved now.